# How to control homework writting machine with IOT

Tags: arduino

It consists of (CNCsheild, Arduino UNO, 2-stepper motors and servo motor), It works with GRBL Plotter and Inkscape.
I am new at learning IOT. I want to know what is the needed components and software that I should add to control the motors.

Comment: How would you like to control it?

Comment: If you want someone to spend some time thinking and writing an answer, you should probably explain what you have and what you want to achieve. Perhaps that will take 100+ words.

Comment: I want to know what should I get to apply the IOT to the system. like what else should I connect to the shield and what is the software I need to install. https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/14558/romkey

Comment: what does `apply the IOT` mean?  ... please describe what you are trying to do ... IOT is not clearly defined